# ACAccountStore Error 6 (ACErrorAccountNotFound) and 8

Tags: ios, ios6

I'm attempting to get an account from ACAccountStore using the following code:

```
- (void) facebookLoginOnSuccess: (void (^)(void)) successBlock onError:(void(^)(NSError *error))errorBlock{

    self.facebookPermissions = @[
        @"offline_access",
        @"publish_stream",
        @"user_birthday",
        @"user_location",
        @"email"
    ];
    
        
    NSDictionary *options = @{
        @"ACFacebookAppIDKey": [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"FacebookAppID"],
        @"ACFacebookAppVersionKey": @"1.0",
        @"ACFacebookPermissionsKey": self.facebookPermissions,
        @"ACFacebookPermissionGroupKey": @"write"
    };
    
    [self accountLoginFor:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook withOptions:options OnSuccess:successBlock onError:errorBlock];

}

- (void) accountLoginFor: (NSString *) accountTypeID withOptions: (NSDictionary *) options OnSuccess: (void (^)(void)) successBlock onError:(void(^)(NSError *error))errorBlock{

    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:accountTypeID];
    
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType
                                          options:options
                                       completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
        if (granted){
            NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
            NSLog(@"%@",accountsArray);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error accessing account: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
    
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=6 "The operation couldn't be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 6.)"
```

And I can't find anything related, just this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437250/acaccountstore-error-5). Any ideas what could be wrong?

**Update**

I found this on the Apple Developer Docs.

> **Accounts Framework**
>
> When requesting access to Facebook accounts, the only key required in your options dictionary is ACFacebookAppIdKey. **ACFacebookPermissionGroupKey and ACFacebookAppVersionKey are now obsolete.**
>
> If you request a write permission under ACFacebookPermissionsKey, **such as publish_stream**, you must provide a value for ACFacebookAudienceKey, which can be one of **ACFacebookAudienceEveryone**, **ACFacebookAudienceFriends**, or **ACFacebookAudienceOnlyMe**.

So I changed my options to:

```
    NSDictionary *options = @{
        @"ACFacebookAppIDKey": [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"FacebookAppID"],
        @"ACFacebookPermissionsKey": self.facebookPermissions,
        @"ACFacebookAudienceKey": ACFacebookAudienceFriends
    };
```

But I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter, but those keys are strings already:
`NSDictionary *options = @{ACFacebookAppIDKey:[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"FacebookAppID"], ACFacebookPermissionsKey:self.facebookPermissions, ACFacebookAudienceKey:ACFacebookAudienceFriends};`

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I'm using the new syntax for defining Dictionaries/Arrays on XCode 4.5 :)

Comment: what jab was saying is that you don't need @"ACFacebookAppID", but can just write ACFacebookAppID. So you can drop the @"" ... however, I agree with him that it shouldn't matter. Try anyway.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ok so if you haven't setup an account from your Settings in iOS 6 it throws error code **6**. If the user simply denies permission than it throws error code **7**. In case 6 i suggest you ask the user to first setup her account in Settings.

```
NSDictionary *options = @{
ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"1234567890",
ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_stream"],
ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends
};

[self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
{
    if (granted)
    {
        NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];

        if([accounts count]>0)
            self.facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
    }
    else
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            // Fail gracefully...
            NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
            if([error code]== ACErrorAccountNotFound)
                [self throwAlertWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Account not found. Please setup your account in settings app."];
            else
                [self throwAlertWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Account access denied."];

        });
    }
}];
```

Comment: I can't test this right now, because I'm using FB SDK, but I think is a better answer than mine.

Comment: hello @jAmi , I have a problem regarding error , when I m displaying log then it executed perfectly but when I am alerting something using UIAlert then it quits , why? As u have done in if condition   if([error code]==6)

Comment: @Khool please check you are not firing the UIAlertView from a background queue

Comment: So instead of using `6`, please use `ACErrorAccountNotFound`.

Comment: remeber: in the first access you should request basic permission, only. after get this, you can request others permissions, like "read_stream" or "publish_stream"

Comment: Is this still working code?  I've read that public_stream is no more.  Is there a workaround?  I can't get it to work with publish_actions the supposed replacement for publish_stream.

Answer (score 4):

jAmi has the right idea, but I don't like the idea of the magic numbers in the code. There is an enum that has the numbers built into it (ACErrorCode).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the ACErrorCode enum.  Much better using it than just specifying an integer

Answer (score 1):

My own solution was to use [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/) instead of trying with the lib directly and now it's working.