# IOS7 - [ACAccountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType - “error code 8”

Tags: ios, objective-c, acaccountstore

I  had already found other topics with this error, but how everybody can see, my NSDictionary is OK - in other answers the problem is the options parameter.

I am using XCode5 and run on IOS7

```
 ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
  ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

  NSDictionary *options = @{ACFacebookAppIdKey : @(FACEBOOK_APP_ID),
                            ACFacebookPermissionsKey : @[@"email", @"publish_stream"],
                            ACFacebookAudienceKey : ACFacebookAudienceFriends};

  [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
   {
     if (granted)
     {
       NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];

       if([accounts count]>0)
       callbackSuccess();

     } else {
       callbackFailure(error);
     }
   }];
```

Similar topics mentioned:

[Getting "Error Code 8" When Calling [ACAccountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType] - iOS Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425325/getting-error-code-8-when-calling-acaccountstore-requestaccesstoaccountswitht)

[ACAccountStore Error 6 (ACErrorAccountNotFound) and 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630066/acaccountstore-error-6-and-8)

Answer (score 0):

After long time spent, I found the problem:

FACEBOOK_APP_ID should be a NSString

Before I declare it as long long

```
static long long *const FACEBOOK_APP_ID = @"249292141827474";
```