# Sharing on twitter without tweetsheet in ios

Tags: objective-c

Hi Good mOrning everyone 
I am sharing on twitter without twitter sheet here i login with twitter my custome button by using this code

```
  [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^
                 (TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
                     if (session) {
                         NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userName]);
                         self.twitter_name_lbl.hidden =NO;
                          self.twitter_name_lbl.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[session userName]];
                          self.Twitterloginstr=@"1";
                     } else {
                         NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

                     }
                 }];
```

after login i sharing using this below code

```
- (IBAction)postbutton_touch:(id)sender
{
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.share_imeg.image);
        ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
        ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

        NSArray *arrayOfAccons = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
       [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
          if (granted == YES) {
                // Populate array with all available Twitter accounts
                NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
                if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0) {
                    ACAccount *acct = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSDictionary *message = @{@"status": @"From my app"};
                    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json"];
                    SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest
                                              requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                              requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                              URL:requestURL parameters:message];
                   [postRequest addMultipartData:data withName:@"media" type:@"image/png" filename:@"TestImage"];
                    postRequest.account = acct;

                    [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:
                     ^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse
                       *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                     {
                         if (error) {
                             NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
                         }
                         else {
                             NSLog(@"Upload Sucess !");
                         }
                     }];
                }
            }
        }];
    }
```

here i got the the problem of accountType is nill i dont know which point i am missing ...any one help me to solved out the problem  Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 "(null)""
Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you try share via uiactivitycontroller?

Comment: it requires twitter install on your device.

Comment: ya i instlled twitter app  on my device ,,my requirement is sharing on twitter without sheet and activity ..

Comment: can you use uiactivitycontroller object for share?

Comment: no actully my requirement is i have to share directly without show any uiactivity or sheet

Comment: i thinks here i ma getting  ACAccountStore  is nill i dont know which point i did mistake

Comment: wherever you have doubt than put log and confirm what wrong their?

Comment: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 "(null)"" Thanks in Advance this is my erreoe log

Comment: that means this code work for your side but data get null .right

Comment: please help to solve this issues

Comment: check this link it may help you

Comment: yes its working but   if (granted == YES)  its falls else statement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12630066/9137841 issue same as yours

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11437250/9137841 check this also

Comment: ok wait i see!!!!

Comment: sorry i cant help without actionsheet or activity